# CtrlV to paste-in data into GitBash?

Tags: windows-10, git-bash

### Simple goal:

Using GitBash for Windows, I would like to be able to paste my clipboard into gitbash **Via CTRL+V**.

### Problem:

Every tutorial I can find says:

1. Right-click on the Git Bash icon and select Properties. Under the
2. Options tab, select QuickEdit Mode and click OK.
3. Restart Git Bash and try pasting again using the right-click menu or Ctrl+V.

In fact, this has some paste shortcuts (**middle mouse**; **CTRL+SHIFT+INSERT**. But I don't like those!

Obviously this doesn't work (I'm here).

### What I've tried:

Poking around like a child with a stick in a puddle.

```
MINIGW 64 Git 2.39.2.windows.1: /z/py
Fri, 0323, 06:45 $ echo -e '"\C-v": paste' > ~/.inputrc
source ~/.inputrc
echo -e '"\e[1;5C": forward-word\n"\e[1;5D": backward-word' > ~/.inputrc
source ~/.inputrc
bash: \C-v:: No such file or directory
bash: $'\E[1;5C:': command not found
bash: $'\E[1;5D:': command not found
MINIGW 64 Git 2.39.2.windows.1: /z/py
Fri, 0323, 06:45 $ echo -e '"\e[1;5C": forward-word\n"\e[1;5D": backward-word' > ~/.inputrc
MINIGW 64 Git 2.39.2.windows.1: /z/py
Fri, 0323, 06:45 $ source ~/.inputrc
bash: $'\E[1;5C:': command not found
bash: $'\E[1;5D:': command not found
MINIGW 64 Git 2.39.2.windows.1: /z/py
Fri, 0323, 06:45 $ ^C
MINIGW 64 Git 2.39.2.windows.1: /z/py
Fri, 0323, 06:45 $ ^[[200~echo -e "\"\e[1;5C\": forward-word\n\"\e[1;5D\": backward-word" > ~/.inputrc
bash: $'\E[200~echo': command not found
MINIGW 64 Git 2.39.2.windows.1: /z/py
Fri, 0323, 06:45 $ echo -e "\"\e[1;5C\": forward-word\n\"\e[1;5D\": backward-word" > ~/.inputrc
MINIGW 64 Git 2.39.2.windows.1: /z/py
Fri, 0323, 06:45 $ source ~/.inputrc
bash: $'\E[1;5C:': command not found
bash: $'\E[1;5D:': command not found
MINIGW 64 Git 2.39.2.windows.1: /z/py
Fri, 0323, 06:45 $
```

AHK script (not working as a workaround):

```
;ahk v1
SingleInstance, Force
^+v:: ;Ctrl+Shift+V.
SendInput %Clipboard% ;Sends the clipboard at keystroke speed.
return ;Exits the hotkey.
```

It would probably be more effective in AHK to do something like assign MiddleMouse, which I think would require the keyboard hook, or to have ctrl+v send shift+insert if that really works, like this:

```
;ahk v1.
#SingleInstance, Force
^v::+{ins}
```

Comment: `Poking around like a child with a stick in a puddle.` .. made my day.  I don't think that this is an option but [Shift]+[Insert] is (old school keys for paste).  Many of us left handed people still use this but it doesn't help you right handed people.

Comment: You could always launch it through an app like ConEmu.

Comment: Okay. I guess I'll try these approaches. I can't figure out how to customize it, but there are a lot of pasting options in the Keyboard and Mouse menu in Options from the top-left dropdown menu. `Middle click`, for example. Thanks!

Comment: You may use a product such as AutoHotKey to map only for git bash the keys ctrl+v to ctrl+shift+insert.

Comment: @harrymc Yeah, I got a ahk keyset, but it doesn't work with gitbash for some reason: 
```ahk v1
^+v::
SendInput %Clipboard%
return
```

Comment: Could you add to your post your AHK script?

Comment: @harrymc Update notification: yes I did that.

Answer (score 1):

Respectfully, just use `shift+ins` unless you have a very important reason not to: you should be using your apps with default settings to the extent that you can because it allows you to work on other devices.

To change that to `ctrl+v` you probably would need to do a custom build: I also tested bash.rc and could not get `ctrl+v` to work.

Comment: Respecfully, why break the standard used everywhere, and if not ctrl+v at least ctrl+shift+v like in most Linux terminals. And my 65% keyboard doesn't have an insert button.